# Django url debugger

Tags: django, debugging, django-urls

I'm developing a django application and over time, the URLs have grown. I have a lot of them with me now and due to some change I made, one view started to malfunction. When I try to GET http://example.com/foo/edit_profile, it's supposed to execute a view certain view function `X` but it's executing `Y` instead. Somewhere the url routing is messing up and I can't figure it out. I used the `django.core.urlresolvers.resolve` method to try it from the shell and I can confirm that the URL is getting wrongly resolved. However, I don't know how to debug this and pinpoint the problem.

Ideally, I'd like to see something like "tested this pattern", "tested this pattern" etc. till it finally finds the correct one and I can then look around where it resolved. I can't find anything like this.

Isn't this a common problem for larger projects? What do people do?

***Update***

I know how the system works and how to look through the URLs one by one. That's what I'm trying to do. This question is basically asking for a shortcut.

Comment: I've yet to see a set of URLs this complex. My `urls.py` tend to have a bunch of includes, each of which has its own unique prefix (e.g. `^foo` would include URLs in the 'foo' app, so I could go there to find out where the next match is coming from. If you're having this problem, your `urls.py` is probably too complicated. We might be able to help you figure out what's wrong if you post it...

Comment: Actually, mine (and all others I've seen) are all "namespaced" (a unique prefix followed by an include). For some reason though, one of my foo/ URLs gets routed to the bar/ application and returns something from there. It'd be nice to have a debugger to just tell me in what order the resolution is attempted so that I can pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

have you already tried to run

```
manage.py show_urls
```

after installing [django_extensions](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-extensions/0.6)?

http://vimeo.com/1720508   - watch from 06:58.

This should give you in what order the url resolution is attempted.

Hope this helps

Comment: Interesting... I wasn't aware of this. Thanks!

Comment: Good idea.  Don't forget you need to add django_extensions to installed_apps before you try to use it https://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation_instructions.html

Answer (score 4):

I would comment out the patterns in your url.py until you get a 404 error when you try to navigate to `foo`. If that pattern is an include, I would recurse down that and comment out lines in that url.py. Eventually you will know exactly which pattern is matching.

Then I would take the view function that it is calling and hard code that. If it is using a generic view or something subtle, I'd make it as obvious and direct as possible. At that point, you should know which rule is matching and why and what code it is executing in the view.

Comment: Okay, how about this: comment out *all* your top level url patterns and after you confirm with a 404, re-enable the one pattern you think is being used. If you're wrong, you learn something. If you're right, drill down into that include (assuming it is an include) and comment out all except what you think is being used. With this shortcut, it should take you five to ten minutes to figure out whether the code you want to use is being used.

Answer (score 1):

You can assume, that it goes through the urlpatterns from top to bottom and the first one that matches will be executed.

As you know which view is executed (`Y`) think about that:

- if `Y` is before `X`: the patterns of Y matches the url (but shouldn't)
- if `X` is before `Y`: the patterns of X doesn't match the url (but should)

Can you provide some more explicit examples of your URLConf? Than I can give you a more explicit answer.

Comment: They're typical. Similar to what Dominic said. I know how they work and your two points are fine. It's just that it's tedious going through the thing manually when trying to get a fix which is why I'm looking for a debugger.

Comment: You can always put in some print lines to the django source, if you really think it helps you. It will just show you that it exactly goes from top to bottom and trying to match every regex untils it matches. MAybe here: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py#L143

Answer (score 0):

Look at your urlconfs, find which urlpattern invokes your view Y and see if the regexp is more general than it ought to be. Try to comment out the urlpattern which causes the false match and see if it correctly matches X.

Typically, this is not a problem for me, but it does occur. Always keep more specific patterns before general ones. Use static prefixes to divide your url namespace, to prevent false matches.

Comment: This gets prohibitively time consuming with the large number of URLs and regexps I currently have. It's what I'm doing right now but I'd like to have a decent "URL debugger" rather than this whole business of commenting out and commenting in lines from the various url files.