# using django url searching without virtual environment

Tags: python, django, url, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am using django 1.9 and am trying to set up a website but I am repeatedly receiving an error pertaining to the "order" of my established urls. I have an "in-app" urls file as well as the already established one in "mysite".

the persistent error is usually something like this:

```
      Using the URLconf defined in herv2.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
          ^admin/
          ^table/$
      The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

I have tried re-ordering my url patterns but there has to be a better solution to this.

One possible explanation for this is that I never use virtual environment. even though i have installed it when I use (working on a mac):

```
     virtualenv .
```

It doesn't recognise the command... and when I try to update the virtualenv package with:

```
     pip install virtualenv --upgrade
```

it returns:

```
     OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/owner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-14.0.1.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'
```

So my questions are:

1. When I get an ordering error for my urls, where is the best place to look usually (I realise this is unrealistic as it could be a thousand things)?
2. Do I keep getting these errors because I'm not using a virtual environment?

Comment: Could you please include the content of your `urls.py` file?

Answer (score 1):

> When I get an ordering error for my urls, where is the best place to look usually (I realise this is unrealistic as it could be a thousand things)?

Here is the relevant topic on the subject: [Django url debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615609/django-url-debugger).

> Do I keep getting these errors because I'm not using a virtual environment?

*Virtual environment itself has nothing to do with the URL routing issues*. It is just an isolated Python environment/sandbox helping to keep things organized. Virtual environments are especially handy when you deal with multiple Python projects with own dependencies on a single machine.

Answer (score 0):

> When I get an ordering error for my urls, where is the best place to
>   look usually (I realise this is unrealistic as it could be a thousand
>   things)?

You are getting this error not because your order of urls are incorrect. Reason is that requested URL is not matching any of URLs in your routing schema. So, it should show you error page with 404 status (Not Found).

> Do I keep getting these errors because I'm not using a virtual
>   environment?

Virtual env can not be related to this error.